# Компиляция python в один exe-шник

Tags: python, pyqt5, exe

Недавно мне в руки попал exe-шник (просто один exe файл, без dll-ок, без доп. файлов и т.д.) и его исходный код на python, программа использует графический интерфейс на Qt5 и множество библиотек, появился вопрос: Как сделать так-же? Никогда ещё на своём опыте такое не видел

Comment: Есть куча видео на ютубе, как код пайтона перегнать в exe. Я пробовал - вроде работает.
Я использовал pyinstaller.
Вот ссылка на одно из видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4&ab_channel=TechWithTim
Конкретно под pyqt5 вроде как есть pyqtdeploy
https://habr.com/ru/post/487900/

Answer (score 2):

У меня получалось все упаковать такой командой для `pyinstaller`:
`pyinstaller -F main.pyw -w -p "Путь к QtDesigner\Qt5Core.dll"`.
Например, `pyinstaller -F main.pyw -w -p "C:\QtDesigner\Qt5Core.dll"`.